# Get list of user and their roles into a view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a model which holds information about a user of this application

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Payroll { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view model which should show some information about the a user and their role

```
public class VM_UserAdmin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Payroll { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

I can get the name, payroll, email as properties of ApplicationUser no problems with this:

```
return await _applicationDbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
```

where _applicationDbContext is my database context.

Can anyone tell me how to reach Roles so I can include this in my VM_UserAdmin model. User.Roles... is no longer available to me in asp.net core 2.1. I have a 1-to-1 relationship of User and Role.

Thanks.

Comment: "I have a 1-to-1 relationship of User and Role" - How? Identity models a M2M between users and roles, and Identity's functionality depends on this type of relationship.

Comment: @chris - sorry, what i meant was in this particular application, a user will only have one role, but that will be managed as a business process

Comment: @KirkLarkin  - agreed. i got what i needed in that post. thanks.